# Does iOS cache remote notifications for apps that are running in background?

Tags: ios, background, push-notification

Official document from apple developer network mentions that the payload of a push notification is provided to an application when it’s running in foreground, or when it’s activated because of a push notification. I cannot find the statement about what happens when the app is running in background.

I did a test with an instant message application, and found something that I do not understand. Procedure of the test is:

1. Enable push notification for the app
2. Switch the app to background
3. Send two IMs to the client. Two push notification arrives at the client and the badge on the app's icon becomes 2
4. Shut down cellular network to prevent the app from communicating with its server
5. Click the app icon to switch it to foreground

After these steps, I can see the 2 messages in the chat window. Because the app is not able to retrieve the messages directly from server, the only explanation is that the push notifications are processed by the app when it’s in background, or they are cached somewhere and can be accessed by the app when it's switched to foreground. But does iOS really allows an app to execute codes when it’s in background, or cache notifications for apps?

Answer (score 0):

The application caches the notifications for 2-5 minutes(i don't know exact) time..

If you receive a notification and you open the app in 2-5 minutes

then in your app delegate

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions

{

}
```

You will have the notification object then .. you can get it using `launchOPtions` object for key `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey`

If you don't open it within 2-5 minutes.. there will be no notification object,

This is based on my experience..cant totally support this answer

Comment: I tried to wait for as long as 1h before I switch the app from background to foreground, but the IM is still there. I guess the cache time has become longer in recent iOS version, or there are still some unknown behaviours of iOS?

Comment: if the app is VOIP app.. then it can execute code in the background.. so if notification comes..then it is executed in app(and stored ..only UI is not updated)..that is the explanation for your IM app .. my answer explanation was for a normal push notification app..